# How to make OpenCV 3.2 package built from source available in Anaconda environment?

Tags: opencv, anaconda, conda

I have built OpenCV 3.2 from source with Visual Studio 2017 under Windows 10, which generated a file `cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` in the build directory, and also copied it to `C:\Users\fanta\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`.

But now, after entering an Anaconda environment for Python 3.6, python doesn't find the package, see transcript below (error at the bottom):

```
C:\Users\fanta>conda create -n py36 python=3.6
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\fanta\Anaconda3\envs\py36:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:            9.0.1-py36_1
    python:         3.6.1-2
    setuptools:     27.2.0-py36_1
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?

#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate py36
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > deactivate py36
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#


C:\Users\fanta>activate py36

(py36) C:\Users\fanta>python
Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

If instead I try to import the `cv2` package from outside any Anaconda environment, I get a different error, see below:

```
(py36) C:\Users\fanta>deactivate py36

C:\Users\fanta>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

How can I make the built `cv2` package available to be imported in an Anaconda environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the right place for the `cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` file is (for my `py36` Anaconda environment):

`C:\Users\fanta\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Lib`

Then I got a `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

To fix the ImportError:

- added the directory with built DLLs for OpenCV to the PATH
  environment variable (`C:\opencv32\build\install\x64\vc15\bin` in my
  case);
- set OPENCV_DIR (to `C:\opencv32\build\install\x64\vc15` in my
  case).

Finally I installed numpy and matplotlib in the Anaconda environment.

Now OpenCV 3.2 built from source with Visual Studio 2017 works.